# I am using TextField in LIST SwiftUI, while entering text on particular textField of row all other rows gets altered?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

This is the TextField used in the List and when i enter some text while using the app all the Texfield of each row gets Affected.

```
                                   TextField("Count", text: $count)
                                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                   .frame(width:70, height: 15,alignment: .center)
                                   .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                                   .padding(4)
                                   .cornerRadius(3)
                                   .font(.system(size: 12))
```

Comment: You need a variable for each row. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: Post more of your code pls, though it seems like you use $count for all of your list's elements